# Removing comments if present, or adding comments if not present, before and after the last matching pattern

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I have an xml file that contains lines of type -

```
    <!--
    <xml:tag.type-one>on</xml:tag.type-one>
    <xml:tag.type-two>off</xml:tag.type-two>
    -->
```

1. I want to remove comments **if they are already present** (as in the case above) before `<xml:tag.type-one>on</xml:tag.type-one>` and after `<xml:tag.type-two>off</xml:tag.type-two>`. If these tags are already not commented, then no change needs to be made.
2. I want to add comments **if they are not already present** before `<xml:tag.type-one>on</xml:tag.type-one>` and after `<xml:tag.type-two>off</xml:tag.type-two>`. If these tags are already commented, then no change needs to be made.

This is what I have been trying -

```
sed -ni '/^\s*<xml:tag.type-one>on<\/xml:tag.type-one>\s*$/{x;d;};1h;1!{x;p;};${x;p;}' path/to/file 
sed -i '/^\s*<xml:tag.type-two>off<\/xml:tag.type-two>\s*$/{N;s/\n.*//;}' path/to/file
```

These commands delete the (`<!--` and `-->` comments) before and after the line if they are present. If not, these commands delete the lines before and after the matching pattern.

How do I delete `<!--` and `-->` before and after the matching pattern only if they are present.
Also, how to make this change only on the **last** occurrence of the matching pattern?

Comment: Are you using GNU sed or another version?

Comment: Yes. I am using `sed (GNU sed) 4.7`.

Comment: Is using an xml parser out of the question?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo - Yes.

Comment: @Ira A reason as for why would help. If there's some artificial reason why not to use one, there are often workarounds. Keep in mind that it's _you_ who is asking for input so please provide _all_ requirements so that people can provide the best possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entire xml data can comfortable fit in memory:

- choose strings that cannot exist in the input to use as markers
- search for desired lines and insert markers
- when comment tags appear next marker, remove both
- replace remaining markers with comment tags

```
# these are regex - escape shell and sed metacharacters
v1='<xml:tag.type-one>on<\/xml:tag.type-one>'
v2='<xml:tag.type-two>off<\/xml:tag.type-two>'
m1='\x00\x01'
m2='\x00\x02'

sed -zE "
    s/[ \t]*$v1\s*$v2[ \t]*\n/$m1&$m2/g
    s/[ \t]*<\!--\s*$m1|$m2\s*-->[ \t]*\n//g
    s/$m1([ \t]*)/\1<\!--\n\1/g
    s/([ \t]*)([^\n]+\n)$m2/\1\2\1-->\n/g
" /path/to/file
```

---

To change only final occurrence, use a greedy match to consume all preceding lines:

```
sed -zE "
  s/(.*\n)?([ \t]*$v1\s*$v2[ \t]*\n)/\1$m1\2$m2/
  s/[ \t]*<\!--\s*$m1|$m2\s*-->[ \t]*\n//g
  s/$m1([ \t]*)/\1<\!--\n\1/g
  s/([ \t]*)([^\n]+\n)$m2/\1\2\1-->\n/g
" /path/to/file
```

Comment: for portability escaped literal newlines are needed on replacement part of `s///` - some implementations treat `\n` there as just `n`